# Convergence in distribution in Skorohod topology

Tags: probability-theory, continuity, normed-spaces, weak-convergence

I have a basic (I think) question which I would like to confirm. Suppose we have a sequence of Cadlag random elements $X_n$ taking values in $D[0,1]=\{G[0,1]\to \mathbb{R} \mid\text{ G is cadlag}\}$. (Here we have the $\mathcal{J}_1$ metric). Suppose further that $X_n\to X$ in distribution (in $D[0,1]$) where $X$ is a random element of $C[0,1]$, the space of continuous functions on $[0,1]$.

If we linearly interpolate $X_n$ to obtain a random element $Y_n=X_n+E_n\in C[0,1]$ where $\|E_n\|_\infty \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$, can we now deduce that $Y_n\to X$ in distribution in $C[0,1]$.

Intuitively I think we can, since the error terms $E_n$ don't contribute much in the limit. I also think the following will be useful: If $f_n\in D[0,1]$ and $f\in C[0,1]$, then $d(f_n,f)\to 0$ implies $\|f_n-f\|_\infty\to 0$. 
Could anyone please give me more intuition, and perhaps an actual proof/counterexample of this?
Thanks!